# my While loop executes everything at once ( C#)

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

So I have this script attached to a game and the While loop I added should keep track of Ammo and go down 1 everytime I shoot a rocket, but instead when I left click in game (shoot) it shoots all my ammo at once. My code:

```
public class CreateRocket : MonoBehaviour {
public Rigidbody rocket;
public float speed = 10f;
public int aantalRaketten;
public int Ammo = 10;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
      FireRocket();
    }
}

void FireRocket()
{      
    while (Ammo >= aantalRaketten) 
    {
      Ammo--;
      Rigidbody rocketClone = (Rigidbody)Instantiate(rocket, transform.position + transform.forward * 2, transform.rotation);
      rocketClone.velocity = transform.forward * speed;         
    } 
  }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Your title doesn't explain your problem. [Write a better one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) instead.

Comment: well... yes! the while loop runs to completion *basically* instantly...

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside the while-loop and start debugging. When the program stops inside of the loop the condition is at least complied once. If this is not your problem specify the problem.

Comment: If you only want to fire one rocket every time you click, you should probably use `if` instead of `while`.

Comment: I had an "if" first, but the assignment is to use a while loop.

Comment: @user2912068 then... the assignment probably has a typo?

Comment: You have misunderstood what a while loop does. The while loop checks a condition and runs the loop over and over until the condition isn't true anymore. Which means it will decrease your ammo until it's below aantalRaketten.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `while` and `if`?

Comment: I dont know why the down vote, any beginner can make this mistake..

Comment: Game engines often contain one big loop, which handles input, runs game logic (your `Update` method) and renders the current game state. At 30 fps, these actions happen 30 times per second. If you want to fire 1 missile per second, you'll have to launch one missile ever 30 `Update` calls. So in each `Update` call, you either launch 0 or 1 missiles, and after launching 1, you'll want to set a cooldown time to prevent launches during the next second.

Comment: Then, during each call to `Update`, you decrease the cooldown time by the amount of time that has elapsed (see `Time.deltaTime`), and you only allow firing another missile if the cooldown time is below 0.

Answer (score 1):

Well: but instead when I left click in game (shoot) it shoots all my ammo at once

Yes that is exactly what you are doing in the while loop, run till you condition is false (aantalRaketten = 0?):

```
while (Ammo >= aantalRaketten) 
{
  Ammo--;
  Rigidbody rocketClone = (Rigidbody)Instantiate(rocket, transform.position + transform.forward * 2, transform.rotation);
  rocketClone.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
}
```

I geuss you need to change the while to a if to check if there are any rockets to fire:

```
if (Ammo > 0) 
{
  Ammo--;
  Rigidbody rocketClone = (Rigidbody)Instantiate(rocket, transform.position + transform.forward * 2, transform.rotation);
  rocketClone.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood what a `while` loop is. The key is the word **loop**. The body of the loop may be executed multiple times:

```
while (Ammo >= aantalRaketten) 
{
    Ammo--;
    ....
}
```

The condition of the loop determines whether or not the body is executed. When the body of the loop completes, the condition is tested again. If the condition evaluates true, then the body executes again. This looping continues until the condition evaluates false.

I presume you meant to write this with an `if` statement.

```
if (Ammo >= aantalRaketten) 
{
    Ammo--;
    ....
}
```

Here, the body executes at most once. If body of the `if` statement executes if the condition evaluates true. There is no looping, no iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the loop! After all you want only one unit of ammo to be dispatched each time you fire a rocket.

Answer (score 0):

when you are invoking `void FireRocket()` once, it comes inside and runs the `while()` loop completely and fires all rockets..

What you want is to have only `if` inside the `void FireRocket()`, to check if `Ammo` is left to shoot or not.. like this

```
if(Ammo >= aantalRaketten)
{
    Ammo--;
    Rigidbody rocketClone = (Rigidbody)Instantiate(rocket, transform.position +  transform.forward * 2, transform.rotation);
    rocketClone.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
}
```

inside the `void FireRocket()`

The `else` will have what you wanna display to the player when `Ammo` is over..